# Accessing in Javascript link passed from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables

So I have this PHP code

```
    </div>
    <div id="topmusicartisttitle">Top 5 Music Artist</div>
    <div class="edit"><a href="" name="topartistsedit">edit</a></div>
    <div id="topmusicartistlist">
    <ul>
    ...
```

that basically passes a list of stuff and I want to be able to click on this a href in javascript but I don't want it to go anywhere I just want to catch the click and handle it. So to start I have:

```
   $('a[name=birthdayedit').live('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  });
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I checked firebug and the href and the name are there (obviously), but the click isn't registered in Javascript and it still redirects. I assume live is the function to use since this is pretty much dynamically created content. Any one know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried including `return false;` in your click handler?

Comment: There's no `birthdayedit` named field in your snippet, and you're missing the closing `]` in the jquery selector.

Comment: `$('a[name=birthdayedit')` is an error. Compare with `$('a[name=birthdayedit]')`.

Comment: If you place a window.alert("CLick"); in the click handler do you get an alert? You might try adding a "]" to close out the "a[name=]" part.

Comment: Your're missing a closing square bracket in `$('a[name=birthdayedit')`. Also, the name there doesn't match the name on your HTML!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several mistakes:

1. There is not closing bracket (a `]`) in `a[name=birthdayedit'`
2. The name attribute in the HTML is different from that which the JS
       references.

Comment: Thanks everyone, somehow I missed that closing bracket. It was also stupid of me to not post the CORRESPONDING section of javascript. I just picked one for some reason instead of the right one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('a[name=birthdayedit')
```

to

```
$('a[name=topartistsedit]')
```

or change the name in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to change your HTML to use an id like this:

```
<div class="edit"><a href="#" id="topartistsedit">edit</a></div>
```

And, then you can capture the click like this:

```
$("#topartistsedit").click(function() {
    // do what you want in the click function
    return(false);   // returning false stops default behavior and propagation
});
```

or if the content is created dynamically after page load:

```
$("#topartistsedit").live("click", function() {
    // do what you want in the click function
    return(false);   // returning false stops default behavior and propagation
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8FgFP/